# Paypal Payment transaction failed in Magento

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment-gateway

I have developed a site few months ago but I am having an issue with paypal Express Checkout
It's giving me this error. this issue arising sometime not all time.

Payment transaction failed. 
Reason
PayPal gateway has rejected request. Express Checkout token is missing (#10408:
Express Checkout token is missing). Express Checkout PayerID is missing (#10419:
Express Checkout PayerID is missing). The PayerID value is invalid (#10406:
Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages

Thanks in advance.
Shivam

Comment: Start with checking the raw request to see if those params are being sent.

Comment: Yes, log the params to see, what is sent or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
The PayerID value is invalid (#10406: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument.
```

Payer simply inputs wrong id?